# PHP Background Search

Tags: php, search, background-process

I have a site where a user will enter some search details, click search and this will send an AJAX request to a PHP script that goes off and does a search for the requested data. This PHP script can take 30 - 60 seconds to run so I don't think it's ideal to keep the user waiting this long.

My ideal setup would be the PHP script goes off and does it's thing (it currently saves partial results to a file whilst gathering everything), the browser could then make a request every ~10 seconds to see if there is anything in this file - instead of waiting for the entire script to finish before anything can be displayed in the browser.

I've been reading up on different people's solutions and there seems to be so many different things. Is this something I could utilise GearMan for? or can it be as simple as closing the connection to the browser when the search is started (I've read peoples conflicting opinions on this one, hacky?)? Any other suggestions?

Comment: What's being searched that takes so long?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey Flight information. It has to send requests to a third party service and do its own processing etc.

Comment: So there's nothing else on the page?  Progress bar time, and show some advertising?

Comment: @Kevin_Kinsey Haven't got that far yet. Ideally I'd like to display results incrementally as it gets them (plus the surrounding interface), hence the idea for polling the server.

Comment: So you want a PHP server that will echo file_get_contents($some_temp_file) when polled by AJAX ... and some AJAX on the page that waits a bit and then does it every $n seconds....

Comment: Or you could use output buffering to show results as they are created

Comment: Do you have any way of querying the third party ahead of time for its information and then storing the results so that you're actually searching your results instead of the third party? Then every X amount of time update your information (request from the third party again). This would allow you to speed up your searches dramatically and instead of your user navigating away from your website because they think it's broken (takes too long, people are impatient nowadays), you're presenting the user with fast search results

Comment: @ctwheels This is what I'm after. It's more about when the user starts the search and then my server goes away and does what it needs to do, how do I get the browser to close that connection (or should I run the search as a background task with GearMan?). Totally with you on presenting the results faster. Hope that makes sense, I know what I'm after it's just the best way of doing it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with GearMan, so I can only provide you with information about how I would go about building a similar application. Assuming the current performance is being limited by the third party's response to your query (and not the speed of your scripts in any other way), I would create a process that runs automatically every X minutes (depending on the time it would actually take to run that query, so for simple numbers, every 5 minutes). The process would query the third party to get all *general* details that your users would *generally* look for. I would then store this data...

Comment: ... In a database locally and any time your users search for *something*, you query your local database for the results. You order by some sort of `datetime` field that would determine the time at which you pulled all the information from the third party application and limit your results to top 1 so that you only get the most recent and relevant information. Inside the application, I would insert a small indicator so that your users can see that the information was last updated at time `X` so that they can refresh the page and requery your local data once again to get the newest information.

Comment: This would allow you to serve the information from the third party with much greater speeds because you're actually querying the third party's API *whenever you feel like it* and your users get the most recent pull of that information with much better speeds. This will also limit the amount of connections you could be making with the third party API (depending on the number of users you have), which may also decrease its cost (if you pay for the service).

Comment: So to sum it up: `3rd Party API --> Local Database` *occurs every X minutes* (interval). `User search --> Local Database Query` *query most recent pull from the 3rd party API on your local database*

Comment: @ctwheels Whilst I think this is the most ideal solution, the issue is the search query is people looking for certain flight price information so it's impossible to predict searches (so many variables). So I have to wait for the user before starting anything. I'm already kind of there with saving the data to a file whilst it searches, it's just that I can't get the browser to close that connection. It's forced to wait for the 'loop' in PHP to finish.

Comment: Well, I don't know which method would be *best* but a couple of methods are as follows: **1** use cURL to send single requests and return each of those results to the user using AJAX. **2** use web sockets (take a look at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) to send data back and forth between the client and yourself so that every time you receive new data, you can send it to the client almost immediately). Web sockets are basically how certain applications (like online web chats) maintain constant communication with the server